# :before элемент залезает внутрь button-а

Tags: button, position

Код:

```
<button class="btn__like">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="like__quantity">236</span> 
</button>

.btn__like {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;

    padding: 0 5px;

    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid darken($gray-lightest, 25%);
    border-radius: 10px;

    i { color: darken($gray-lightest, 25%); }
}

.btn__like::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 46px;
    height: 22px;

    background: url('../img/likes.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

Должно быть: 
    [image: Макет]

На данный момент:
    [image: Мой результат]

Comment: А css мы должны сами угадать?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn__like {
  position: reletive;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;

    padding: 0 5px;

    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid darken($gray-lightest, 25%);
    border-radius: 10px;

    i { color: darken($gray-lightest, 25%); }
}

.btn__like::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  rigth: 0;
    content: '';
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 46px;
    height: 22px;

    background: url('../img/likes.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn__like">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="like__quantity">236</span> 
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Незачто, рад что помог =)